# Postman не видит локальный адрес и не отправляет запрос Mac OS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, macos, postman

На Mac OS postman не видит адрес: http://localhost:8080/auth/users
Запросы не отправляются. Вернее бесконечно долго висит Sending request...
Помогите решить данную проблему. Может кто знает как исправить
[image: Бесконечное Sending request...]
[image: Сервер стартует]
[image: Обработчик запросов]
[image: Роутинг]

Comment: Вангую, что проблема не с постманом, а с сервером. Скорее ваш сервер на запрос постмана держит await. Если бы что то было не так, он бы сразу выдал ошибку.

Answer (score 0):

Я конечно могу ошибаться, но почему в index.js вы в строке app.use('./auth.js', authRouter) прописываете именно путь ./auth? Попробуйте заменить этот путь просто на /auth.

Comment: Кстати да, но даже если путь ошибочный, то постман выдаст ошибку.

Comment: @MrYogurt, Я тоже работаю с Postman и иногда у меня тоже бесконечная надпись даже если роутер рабочий.

Comment: Ну вот я погуглил эту тему и пишут, что сам постман может забаговать, ждем, пока тс его переустановит.

Comment: @MrYogurt увы переустановка не помогла. С путем проступил это да)

Comment: @Павел Саенко, попробуйте просто ввести путь для проверки в браузер.

Comment: @alexseybobrovitch Тоже самое. бесконечно грузится, а толку 0

Comment: @ПавелСаенко значит у вас сервер обнаруживается, но он занят чем то и не может ответить на запрос, из за чего он висит в ожидании.

Comment: @MrYogurt пересоздал полностью проект. Благо кода не много. И все завелось. Наверное webStorm что-то не поделил с postman. Спасибо за помощь всем)